# Find out localized text of Carrier dependent Messages option

Tags: ios, localization, imessage

There is a carrier dependent option in iOS called **"Group Messaging"** in **Settings > Messages**. See this [image](http://www.astekblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/disable-group-mms.png).

I would like to find out what the name of this option is in Swedish, but unfortunately this option is not available for my carrier so how would I find out what it is called? I could of course just do a direct translation with Google Translate but I would like to find out what the exact naming is.

Is there a way to browse strings or something in the iOS SDK?

**EDIT**: It would also be nice to find out which carriers are supporting this option. I think at least in Sweden there are no carriers supporting this option. In USA I believe AT&T and Verizon support it.

Comment: If it were a string in OSX you could download the AppleGlot translations that Apple publishes at https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/. But I don't know where to find the same for iOS.